# What happens if the basic pay is increased, and allowances decreased for the same overall salary?

Tags: salary, india

The employer has changed the salary structure from the one which was shared before joining, now they have increased the basic pay and decreased the special allowance with negligible change in the overall salary.
What is the significance of this? What does the above changes indicate?

Comment: It is in Indo pacific

Comment: In your company, is **basic pay** always guaranteed while **special allowance** can vary from 1 year to another depending on the amount of profit the company makes ?

Comment: Have they said why they are doing it?

Comment: @OldNick I have not asked them as I don't expect them to say true reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Kilisi's answer is unnecessarily negative in my opinion. Is it not better for employees to have a reliable higher basic pay? Rather than to have a lower basic pay which might (or might not) be supplemented with "special allowances"? Also depending on your location a higher basic pay might mean higher social security payments in case of unemployment or sickness.

So why would an employer do such a thing? Just some reasons out the top of my head.

- They just want to do the right thing for their employees.
- Paying their employees through these "special allowances" instead of basic pay might give some tax benefits. However it is in a legal gray area. They might just not want to risk legal/tax trouble over this anymore.
- They have trouble finding new employees, when these potential new employees face (some) uncertainty about their income.

Comment: One other thing that might be added to this list is payroll stability. Some companies can't handle the fluctuations that come with "special allowances" whether it's commission, bonuses, cost of living, subsistence grants, whatever the case. Smaller companies may want stability for the P and L. Larger companies often have specific budgets for various things, and they may be attempting to control their cash structure by making sure that basic pay is consistent and predictable.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: answerer doesn't "know". They're suggesting a possibility why.

Answer (score -7):

> What is the significance of this?

It means they're playing games with the remuneration. Usually a red flag or they have someone new on board in charge.

Changes are rarely made for the benefit of staff, and when they are it's usually made a big deal of.

Comment: Correct, don't know who downvoted this unless they are a manager who does this to people's pay...

Comment: Do you mean to say someone new in managing HR?

Comment: @SolarMike Pleae explain how having lower base salary and higher "bonuses" which are not guaranteed, is more favorable?

Comment: @Jack where does the answer, or I, say “more favourable”?

Comment: @Jack nothing to do with favourable. At face value it seems fine, but so does a free lollipop from a guy in a van while walking to school.

Comment: @Jack these special allowances IMO are not variable like performance based bonus.

Comment: It is in India.

Comment: This answer is not wrong in that this is indeed a _possible_ explanation; but it is wrong in asserting that this is definitely the case. Judging whether the change is to OP's benefit requires knowledge of the financial implications; and it should not be based on some cynical assumption that change can never be good.